# Execution time of Breadth-first search

Tags: algorithm, time, breadth-first-search

I am looking at the algorithm of  Breadth-first search, that is the following:

```
BFS(G,s)
 for each u ∈ V\ {s}
     color(u)=white
     d(u)=oo
     π(u)=NIL
 color(s)=GRAY
 d(s)=0
 π(s)=NIL
 Q=∅
 ENQUEUE(Q,s)
 while (Q!=∅)
    u=DEQUEUE(Q)
    for each v ∈ Adj(u)
         if (color(v)=white)
             color(v)=GRAY
             d(v)=d(u)+1
             π(v)=u
             ENQUEUE(Q,v)
    color(v)=BLACK
```

I thought that it is like that:
The time complexity of the first for loop is O(V).
The time complexity of the while-loop is O(V), while the time complexity of the for loop that is executed inside the while-loop is O(E).
Then the time complexity of the algorithm would be O(VE+E)=O(VE).
But, according to my textbook it is O(V+E).
So, have I calculated something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since it's a worst case your analysis is correct but not tight. The while loop runs as long as there are vertices in the queue. Only vertices whose color is WHITE are enqueued in which case their color becomes GRAY so they will never be enqueued again. This tells you that the queue can get as large as V.

In each iteration you iterate over the adjacency list of a vertex so the overall running time is the sum of the lengths of the adjacency lists + V. The sum is O(E). The running time is O(V+E).

It might be useful to remember that in an undirected graph, the following holds: `sum of degrees of all vertices = 2 * E`. To see this, note that every edge (x,y) will be counted twice: once in the degree of x and once in the degree of y.

Comment: I haven't understood why the overall running time of the while-loop is the sum of the lengths of the adjacency lists + V. Could you explain it further to me? Also how can we use the last proposition you wrote?

Comment: For every item x on queue, for loop takes O(ADJ(x)), do you agree?

Comment: So if the queue has items x1, x2, ..., xn, the running time will be O(ADJ(x1) + ADJ(x2) + ... + ADJ(xn)). The length of ADJ(x) is just the degree of x so use the proposition to get the result. Do you get it?

Comment: If we have a outer loop and an inner loop isn't the complexity of the outer loop the product of the two? Or am I wrong?

Comment: That's correct  but in our case the running time of the inner loop is not always the same, it depends on the length of the adjacency list of node u. I'll update my answer to elaborate on this.

Comment: So at each iteration, the time complexity is equal to O(degree of node we are looking at), right?

Comment: Nice :) Could you explain me how we could conclude that sum of degrees of all vertices = 2 * E?

Answer (score 1):

No, the algorithm really is O(VE), but it's also O(V + E). Your bound is loose because each edge is considered at most twice when scanning the adjacency lists.

Comment: David Could you explain me why each edge is considered at most twice when scanning the adjacency lists and not only once? :/

Comment: @evinda Same deal -- at most once implies at most twice. I wasn't sure whether your graph is directed (once) or undirected (twice).

Comment: The graph is undirected. So what does this mean?

Comment: @evinda Each edge gets scanned in both directions.